# How to remove permission to all users for a directory and subdirectory using command line in windows?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a Directory Test and it has many subdirectories and files. I need to remove default permissions set to the directory and subdirectories.

I used below command 
Icacls C:\Test /inheritance:r /T

It is removing all permissions, but it is taking 6 mins to remove for all files and subdirectories under a directory,(Since we have some thousand files)

Is there any alternative, where we can remove default permissions. So that i can apply new permission

Answer (score 1):

You can use it as follows:
CACLS files /e /p {USERNAME}:{PERMISSION}

Where,

/p : Set new permission

/e : Edit permission and kept old permission as it is i.e. edit ACL instead of replacing it.

{USERNAME} : Name of user

{PERMISSION} : Permission can be:

**D - Deny**

R - Read

W - Write

C - Change (write)

F - Full control

For example grant Rocky Full (F) control with following command (type at Windows command prompt):

C:> CACLS files /e /p rocky:f

Read complete help by typing following command:

C:> cacls /?

or [This Link](http://www.virtualhelp.me/windows/691-change-access-permissions-in-command-prompt)